# Why does the reflected component in Lambertian path tracing get multiplied by a factor of 2?

Tags: rendering, pathtracing, mathematics

I would like to intuitively understand the [Path Tracing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_tracing#Algorithm) equation/formula/pseudocode, but I'm not fully getting the last `return` statement.
As per Wikipedia page:

```
// Probability of the newRay
const float p = 1/(2*M_PI);
// Compute the BRDF for this ray (assuming Lambertian reflection)
float cos_theta = DotProduct(newRay.direction, ray.normalWhereObjWasHit);
Color BRDF = material.reflectance / M_PI ;
...
// Apply the Rendering Equation here.
return emittance + (BRDF * incoming * cos_theta / p);
```

I would understand:

- *p* is the probability of new ray (not quite sure what this means), though it's `1 / (2 * PI)`
- *cos_theta* is the angle between the normal of a given surface and the *incoming* ray
- *BRDF* is the material colour divided by `PI`
- After computing the *incoming* colour, we add the *emittance* component with the *Lambertian*

I would interpret the second part of the return statement as:

1. Reflect current colour based on how much is incoming `BRDF * incoming`
2. "Weight" it by the angle (rays that are next to the *normal* would reflect more colour, energy) `* cos_theta`
3. But then we `/ p`, which if we consider the *BRDF*, removed the PI component and leave a factor of **2** (`BRDF / p = material.reflectance / M_PI * (2 * M_PI) = material.reflectance * 2`)

Why is there such factor of **2**?
What is the most logical explanation to this?

Comment: The division by $\pi$ in the brdf's constant is for energy preservation (then `material.reflectance` can be anything in `[0,1]`). This is unrelated to the division by $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ which is due to the pdf. The pdf is $\frac{1}{2\pi}$, since the probability of uniformly generating any point on the upper hemisphere is $\frac{\sin\theta}{2\pi}$. The $\sin\theta$ gets canceled with a term from the rendering equation, and $2\pi$ is the surface area of the unit hemisphere (the whole sphere has area $4\pi r^2$, and $r=1$ for the unit sphere).

Comment: Thanks for this, so it's a chance that 2 factor gets left there. Do you have a link to the full equation you mentioned there?

Comment: The rendering equation? Search for rendering equation in google/wikipedia.